# JBoss cluster does not deploy war when infinispan/jgroups timeouts

Tags: jboss, infinispan, jgroups

I have a jboss cluster composed of two jboss eap 6.3.3 instances. In some cases because an application presents a bug two instances raises an exception and I must to restart these two instances (node1 - node 2).

In that situtation when I restart the node1, for instance, and the node 2 is not reachable because is stalled, the node1 start the deploy of my app war and logs the following exception.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] [] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 107) MSC000001: 
Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."app.war#persistencename":
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."app.war#persistencename":
org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void
org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.start() throws 
java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
...

Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: org.jgroups.TimeoutException: timeout sending 
message to node2/hibernate
    at org.infinispan.util.Util.rewrapAsCacheException(Util.java:542)
...
Caused by: org.jgroups.TimeoutException: timeout sending
message to node2/hibernate
    at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher.sendMessage(MessageDispatcher.java:392)
```

After that Jboss logs that the implementation of the war has failed.

If I restart the node 2 too, then the node1 starts without problems and deploys the war succesfully.

Why does the deployment stop if one node of the cluster is not reachable?

Comment: Migrate: This is not a programming question, but about server administration/configuration (i.e. ServerFault). Also, I removed the incorrect tag [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka: clustering, a data mining task).

Comment: Maybe you can get some stacktrace dumps when this happens to see what is happening? Could be a network configuration issue, so you could try to switch from UDP to TCP or viceversa depending on your configuration. Also try newer EAP versions too?